# how to match hashed password in laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I am working on change password function in laravel4 . I got stuck into one point that how to match hashed password on database with the new password we enter.
I know this that laravel4 Auth produces new hash value every time for the same input .

Please help me on this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear why do u want match the new password with old ?

But to check the password you can do

```
Hash:check($entered_old_password, $password_from_db);
```

*$password_from_db - would be hashed password.

I typically have a form with 3 text inputs, 1 for old password and 1 for new password and the last one for new password confirmation.

On submit check if the old password matchs if so update the user's password with the new one.

You can also use Eloquent Accessor & Mutators to Hash password every time it is set so you don't have to do that in multiple places

[[http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators]](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Is that what you are looking for?